# I am not able to run program coz of this error

Tags: reactjs

I am designing Netflix clone and is working fine but when I uncomment Banner component in my App.js file , its showing error
error:
./src/axios.js 10:12
Module parse failed: Cannot use keyword 'await' outside an async function (10:12)
File was processed with these loaders:

```
 * ./node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
```

You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.

```
const baseURL =
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=API_KEY"; 

const res = await axios.get(
  "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week?api_key=API_KEY&language=en-US"
);

console.log(res);     
instance.get("/foo-bar");
```

Comment: Please share the entire code where you get the error. You need an `async` function to use the keyword `await`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use await always inside the asynchronous function below is the syntax.

```
    const functionName = async () => {
        await axios(************)
    }

    async function functionName(){
        await axios(*********)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to use await inside of an async function only.

```
const fName = async() => {
     const res = await axios.get('https://api.themoviedb.org/3/trending/all/week? 
     api_key=b0d1867018a029a8bfcc00a0d74c1e2f&language=en-US');
     console.log(res);
     instance. Get('/foo-bar')
}
```